# sacar la media aritmetica de numeros pares e impares

Tags: c

pregunta hice este codigo en lenguaje c que pide
Leer N valores desde teclado y mostrar la media de los pares y la media de los impares.
pero me marca error y no muestra bien los resultados podrian decirme que estoy haciendo mal y el como seria?

```
include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float suma2, suma1, media1, media2;
  int i=0, numim=0, numpa=0, cantidad, numero;
  printf("Da la cantidad de numeros a leer:  ");
  scanf("%i", &cantidad);

  do
  {
    printf("\nDa un numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &numero);
    i++;
  }while(i<cantidad);

  do
  {
    if(numero%2==0)
      suma1=numpa+numero;
    else
      suma2=numim+numero;
    i++;
  }while(i<cantidad);

  media1=suma1/cantidad;
  media2=suma2/cantidad;
  printf("\nLa media par es: %f ", media1);
  printf("\nLa media impar es: %f ", media2);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer solo hace falta corregir algunas partes lógicas del código para poder obtener el resultado que quieres, solo hace falta ir sumando los números en el mismo bucle, y a la vez comprobar si estos son pares o impares, luego de eso se podrá sacar las medias de cada parte, ejemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float suma_pares = 0, suma_impares = 0, media_pares, media_impares;
    int i=0, numeros_impar=0, numeros_par=0, cantidad, numero;
    printf("Da la cantidad de numeros a leer:  ");
    scanf("%i", &cantidad);

    do
    {
        printf("\nDa un numero: ");
        scanf("%i", &numero);
    
        if(numero%2 == 0)           // si el numero recientemente digitado es par
        {
            suma_pares += numero;   // sumarlo a la variable de suma_pares
            numeros_par++;          // ir sumando la cantidad de pares digitados
        }
        else                        // si no (es impar)
        {
            suma_impares += numero; //sumarlo a la variable de suma_impares
            numeros_impar++;        // ir sumando la cantidad de impares digitados
        }
        i++;
    }while(i<cantidad);
    
    // La media se calcula sumando todos los valores y dividiendo la suma entre el número total de valores.
    media_pares = suma_pares/numeros_par;
    media_impares = suma_impares/numeros_impar;
    
    printf("\nLa media par es: %f ", media_pares);
    printf("\nLa media impar es: %f ", media_impares);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Noté que se te había olvidado poner '#' antes de que incluyeras la librería **stdio.h**, recuerda verificar esto antes de compilar el programa.

**Recomendación:**

Usar un **for** haría el código mas legible y simple de interpretar:

```
// Bucle del código
for(int i=0 ; i< cantidad ; i++) // En este caso, la variable 'i' no tendría necesidad de ser declarada antes del bucle
{
    printf("\nDa un numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &numero);
        
    if(numero%2 == 0)           
    {
        suma_pares += numero;   
        numeros_par++;          
    }
    else                        
    {
        suma_impares += numero; 
        numeros_impar++;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La suma de la cantidades la debes hacer dentro del primer do-while, lo que estas haciendo en la variable numero en el segundo do-while es asignarle solo el último valor introducido, no haciendo la suma, con esto puedes hacer algo como:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float suma2, suma1, media1, media2;
  int i=0, numim=0, numpa=0, cantidad, numero;
  printf("Da la cantidad de numeros a leer:  ");
  scanf("%i", &cantidad);

  do {
    printf("\nDa un numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &numero);
    if (numero % 2 == 0) {
      suma1 = suma1 + numero;
    }
    else {
      suma2 = suma2 + numero;
    }
    i = i + 1;
  } while(i<cantidad);


    media1= suma1/cantidad;
    media2= suma2/cantidad;
    printf("\nLa media par es: %f ", media1);
    printf("\nLa media impar es: %f ", media2);

    return 0;
}
```